# RabbitMq logs filling with {{badmatch,{error,access_refused}}, consuming disk space

Tags: rabbitmq

We were facing a problem in a busy production cluster, where the log files were quickly filling, and consuming the entire disk (40Gb) in a matter of days.

The errors we saw were:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 19-Jul-2019::12:01:41 ===
** Generic server <0.13892.127> terminating
** Last message in was {'$gen_cast',init}
** When Server state == {state,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,
                            {<<"prod1">>,
                             <<"Move from My_Queue_Name">>},
                            dynamic,
                            {shovel,
                                {endpoint,
                                    ["amqp:///prod1"],
                                    #Fun<rabbit_shovel_parameters.4.75090704>},
                                {endpoint,
                                    ["amqp:///prod1"],
                                    #Fun<rabbit_shovel_parameters.5.120532295>},
                                1000,on_confirm,
                                #Fun<rabbit_shovel_parameters.6.48689962>,
                                #Fun<rabbit_shovel_parameters.7.130815760>,
                                <<"My_Queue_Name">>,
                                1,'queue-length'},
                            undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined,undefined}
** Reason for termination == 
** {{badmatch,{error,access_refused}},
    [{rabbit_shovel_worker,make_conn_and_chan,1,[]},
     {rabbit_shovel_worker,handle_cast,2,[]},
     {gen_server2,handle_msg,2,[]},
     {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,240}]}]}
```

Whilst the queue name did vary between about 10 different queues, we saw the same error logging out over, and over, and over.

Answer (score 0):

What we noticed quite late into dealing with the incident was that the name of the virtual host within the shovel parameters (`amqp:///prod1`) related actually to an old vhost which we had deleted weeks ago.

It seems that when we deleted this vhost, there were still queues within the host. Internally, this seemed to have put RabbitMq into a bad state, and there was still some lingering shovel configurations related to a queue which "sort-of" existed, I'm no Rabbit expert so make an assumption that deleting the vhost does not delete the queues even though you never then see them on the UI and it gets itself confused.

The solution here was to re-create the vhost with the same name, then we can see and delete all the queues, then re-delete the vhost. This stopped the errors and the log files are no longer growing exponentially.